# Swiper won't resume autoplay after mousewheel

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I'm having some problems with autoplay and mousewheel functions on swiper.

After I use the mousewheel to move the slider it won't resume the autoplay. Right now I have the disableOnInteraction option set to false and it works as it should when I drag n drop the slider, but it's not working after the mousewheel is fired/used.

Any suggestions on how to resume the autoplay after the mousewheel event "ends"?

Here's my current code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-slider swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">

        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                1
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                2
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                3
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                4
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                5
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                6
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                7
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                8
            </a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-slide">
            <a href="#" class="box">
                9
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.gallery-slider {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;

    .swiper-slide {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        .box {
            width: 90%;
            height: 80%;
            display: flex;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            transition: .3s;
            background: red;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            color: white;
            font-size: 60px;
            text-decoration: none;

            &:hover,
            &:focus {
                transform: scale(1.1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
const gallery_slider = new Swiper ('.gallery-slider', {
    slidesPerView: 2.5,
    loopedSlides: 3,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 0,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: 10000,
    loop: true,
    touchRatio: .3,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    effect: 'slide',
    simulateTouch: true,
    freeMode: {
        enabled: true
    },
    mousewheel: {
        sensitivity: .5,
    }
});
```

And here's the link to the codepen:
https://codepen.io/flaviort/pen/NWgjjKv

Thanks!